# How to use SHA512 in CakePHP Auth Component?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a strange problem using Auth Component.

This is my **AppController.php**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('Security', 'Utility');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        Security::setHash('sha512');        
    }
}
```

As you can see I set sha512 as hash.
Now, using AuthComponent I see that the password is not hashed with sha512 but still with sha1, the query Auth Component does is:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`pwd`, `User`.`nome` FROM `example`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email` = 'example@example.com' AND `User`.`pwd` = '62d09334d3815d28143792ba12cd386bb7417e1e' LIMIT 1
```

The password is clearly **not** sha512.

How to force sha512 in AuthComponent ?

Thanks

Comment: did you check if your php evirvonment is able to produce sha512? try a native call and see if it returns sth. also you can check hash_algos()

Comment: @mark I can do hash('sha512','hello') without problema.I do not think Its a ENV problem

Comment: my guess: you forgot to call parent::beforeFilter() in your users controller - hence the hash change is never invoked. also the order is relevant. maybe you call the hashing itself earlier than your setHash call.

Comment: @mark beforeFilter in appcontroller will always called....i put parent::beforeFilter() there. Btw I do not have beforeFilter() in UserCOntroller, do you think it should be the problem?

Comment: no then it should not be the source of the problem. debug your setHash call. if it is invoked. also debug the state of $hashType in Security class prior to the hashing call.